# Cannot edit Android Manifest file in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-manifest

I am using Eclipse with the Android plugin. I am trying to change some attributes in my manifest file for an android app. I open it from package explorer and then it opens, but I cannot edit any of the attributes. I am in the Application tab. I can't click on the browse buttons or bring focus to the text boxes.

I have tried closing Eclipse and restarting it, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Try this way when you open AndroidManifest.xml file look at bottom it shown various tab now you select "AndroidManifest.xml" and it shown xml tag code of AndroidManifest.xml file here you can edit also.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the tab as shown in image attached.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to be in the Application tab and edit the text fields in that as I don't yet know XML syntax. I am on the Application page, but I can't enter anything into the text boxes or click any of the buttons on the page.